# Seg Faulting Pointers in C++ when pointing deleting and pointing to a different object

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm beginning to work with pointers in C++ and I feel that I must be missing a key element between C and C++.

I have a member function in a class that does a comparison and then changes what a pointer points to:

```cpp
void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix, matrix* largermatrix, matrix* smallerMatrix)
{
    if(leftSize >= rightSize)
    {
        *largermatrix = leftMatrix;
        *smallerMatrix = rightMatrix;
    }
    else
    {
        *largermatrix = rightMatrix;
        *smallerMatrix = leftMatrix;
    }
}
```

Originally my call was:

```cpp
matrix* largerSized = nullptr;
matrix* smallerSized =  nullptr;

largerSmallerSetter(LeftMatrix.getNumPieces(), RightMatrix.getNumPieces(), leftMemory, rightMemory, largerSized, smallerSized);
```

This creates an error. Which is due to the fact that largerSized and smallerSized live at the address 0x0.

So then I thought I would make sure the pointer is initialized using.

```cpp
matrix* largerSized = new matrix();
matrix* smallerSized = new matrix();
```

However, this new matrix is completely useless, so I want to get rid of the actual "new matrix" and I just want the pointer to point to an existing one. So I added delete calls to delete the object. When I try to reassign the pointer to a different object I get a seg fault.

Now in C, when I would create a pointer with malloc, I was able to then free that pointer. And the pointer still existed for me to point to somewhere else.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want without creating a bunch of objects that are just going to hang out in memory and be memory leaks?

I thought about using std::shared_ptr. But when I reassign the pointer, I was concerned that when it hit the end of scope, it would try to delete the object that I was pointing to, which was created at a higher scope and needs to continue to exist. So I'm not necessarily interested in a smart pointer.

The other thing I tried was:

```cpp
void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix, matrix* largermatrix, matrix* smallerMatrix)
{
    if(leftSize >= rightSize)
    {
        largermatrix = &leftMatrix;
        smallerMatrix = &rightMatrix;
    }
    else
    {
        largermatrix = &rightMatrix;
        smallerMatrix = &leftMatrix;
    }
}
```

But all this does, is when the scope ends, the pointers passed in go back to what they were before the function was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at what your code does.

```
*largermatrix = leftMatrix;
```

It dereferences `largermatrix` (thus getting the piece of memory that the pointer points to) and tries to fill it with the content of `leftMatrix` using the assignment operator (can be a custom action if you have a custom overload for that operator). Therefore, if `largermatrix` points to nothing, you will get the problem you described.

On the other hand,

```
largermatrix = &leftMatrix;
```

This will assign `largermatrix` to point to the location of `leftMatrix`, which is what you want. However, since `largermatrix` is a local variable, changes will not propagate to the caller. Hence, `largermatrix` should be a reference to a pointer.

```
void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, 
                                    matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix,
                                    matrix*& largermatrix, matrix*& smallerMatrix)
```

Btw, it is good practice that other by-reference parameters that the function will not change are const-references like so:

```
void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, 
                                    const matrix& leftMatrix, const matrix& rightMatrix, 
                                    matrix*& largermatrix, matrix*& smallerMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can use to compare two matrix:

1. Better choice would be to return the address of the smallest Matrix. For example,

   ```
   matrix *thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix)
   {
       if(leftSize >= rightSize)
           return &rightMatrix;
       return &leftMatrix;
   }
   ```
2. You can overload comparsion operator in `C++`

   ```
   bool operator<(const matrix& a, const matrix& b)
   {
       return a.getNumPieces() < b.getNumPieces();
   }
   ```
3. You can use pointer-to-pointer in C++.

   ```
   void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix, matrix** largermatrix, matrix** smallerMatrix)
   {
       if(leftSize >= rightSize)
       {
           *largermatrix = &leftMatrix;
           *smallerMatrix = &rightMatrix;
       }
       else
       {
           *largermatrix = &rightMatrix;
           *smallerMatrix = &leftMatrix;
       }
   }
   ```
4. You can have reference-to-pointer.

   ```
   void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize, matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix, matrix*& largermatrix, matrix*& smallerMatrix)
   {
       if(leftSize >= rightSize)
       {
           largermatrix = &leftMatrix;
           smallerMatrix = &rightMatrix;
       }
       else
       {
           largermatrix = &rightMatrix;
           smallerMatrix = &leftMatrix;
       }
   }
   ```

My remarks on your question:

> I have a member function in a class that does a comparison and then changes what a pointer points to:

To change the value of any object, you need to either pass it as reference or pass it as a pointer. In your case, you need to change the value of your pointer, then you need to either pass `pointer as reference` or pass the address of the pointer. Otherwise, your function will be altering it's own local copy of pointer.

> This creates an error. Which is due to the fact that largerSized and smallerSized live at the address 0x0.

It is because in your function, you were trying to copy one matrix to a matrix being pointed by your pointer (`largermatrix` and `smallerMatrix`). However, they don't point to any valid object. You need to use `new` to dynamically allocate an object or pass address of pre-allocated matrix allocated somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a member function in a class that does a comparison and then changes what a pointer points to

No, you have a function that *assigns to the object pointed to by a pointer*.  The `*` operator, in this case, *dereferences* the pointer yielding the object pointed to.  If the pointer doesn't point to an object then its behavior is undefined.

> But all this does, is when the scope ends, the pointers passed in go back to what they were before the function was called.

No, the original pointers passed to the function *were never changed*.  Pointers are objects, and like all objects are passed *by value* by default.  That means that, for instance, `largerSized` and `largermatrix` are totally separate objects.  Their only relationship is that they initially have the same value when you call your function.  Changing the value of `largermatrix` does not modify the value of `largerSized`.  If you want the assignment within your function to modify the passed object, you need to pass a reference:

```
void thisClass::largerSmallerSetter(int leftSize, int rightSize,
                                    matrix& leftMatrix, matrix& rightMatrix,
                                    matrix*& largermatrix, matrix*& smallerMatrix)
// passed by reference --------------------^----------------------^
```

---

Note: This all applies to C as well.  C doesn't have references, but you would need to pass a pointer to a pointer to modify the pointer in the calling scope from within a function.